# OrientDB 1.7.9 cannot start console

Tags: console, orientdb

I've downloaded orientdb-community-1.7.9 for windows.
I start the server running server.bat, it's ok. I can manipulate the database with java and web studio.

But when I run console.bat in bin directory, the cmd window starts but nothing happen: no message, and no prompt.

Comment: Thanks. It works with jdk1.8.0_25 (I was using jdk1.7.0_55).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check if Java is available **from the command line** (must be Java 6+, Java 8 highly recommended)

```
C:\apps\orientdb-community-1.7.9\bin>java -version
java version "1.8.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)
```

For least surprises (not mandatory), also assure that `JAVA_HOME` and `ORIENTDB_HOME` are set. To check:

```
C:\apps\orientdb-community-1.7.9\bin>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_43

C:\apps\orientdb-community-1.7.9\bin>echo %ORIENTDB_HOME%
C:\apps\orientdb-community-1.7.9
```

(and yes, JAVA_HOME points to another Java version, ignore this for now. Not relevant for this example)

Comment: I think %ORIENTDB_HOME% does not have to be set. For me it's working without, too. But sure JAVA should be known. Could you also try starting console.bat via cmd.exe and not via doubleclicking. Thanks.

Comment: @kwoxer That is stated in my answer: "For least surprises (not mandatory)". Also JAVA_HOME is not always needed, as the startup script defaults to "java", and in most use cases this command is known by the os

Comment: Ohh didn't see that sry.